# Unknown Runtime Error VB

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript

I have a VB script that runs a macro in an excel file. 
The code runs and produces the result file correctly.

The Excel Macro runs fine on it's own.
I get an error after the VB code saying 'Unknown runtime error'
                                     'Code 800A9C68'
                                     'Line 8''Char 2'

Code:

```
Dim xlApp, xlBook
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False
Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("Z:\Confidential Restricted\Weekly_HR_Employees_Macro.xlsm", False)

'msgbox("3")

xlApp.Run "Weekly_HR_Employees_Macro.Weekly_HR_Employees_Macro"

'xlbook.Save
'xlBook.Close False
'set xlBook = Nothing

xlApp.Quit
'Set xlApp = Nothing
```

Comment: Look at the duplicate, you need to check you haven't left other excel processes running, that is the cause of error `800A9C68`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the VBScript below:

```
Option Explicit

Dim xlApp, xlBook
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("Z:\Confidential Restricted\Weekly_HR_Employees_Macro.xlsm",0, False)
xlApp.Run "Weekly_HR_Employees_Macro"
xlBook.Close True
xlApp.Quit

set xlBook = Nothing
Set xlApp = Nothing
```

Comment: I'm now getting an error saying object required for the second line?

Comment: @E_McAndrew do you have a `Sub Weekly_HR_Employees_Macro` in your file "Weekly_HR_Employees_Macro.xlsm" ? by the exact name

Comment: Yes I do. The script works, I just don't want the error message

Comment: @E_McAndrew  can u upload your entire script ?

Comment: That is the entire VB script. I don't want to upload the macro due to data issues. The macro runs fine manually.

Comment: @E_McAndrew  try removing all the lines with comments

Comment: @E_McAndrew you say the script works but I'm sorry I don't believe you, it may work in part but then fail when it hits the cause of error `800A9C68`, that doesn't mean the script was successful.

Comment: Well it produces the file and carries out every step. The On Error answer did exactly what I wanted

Comment: @E_McAndrew I've never known an error not to be important, using `On Error Resume Next` is like taking a sledgehammer to the problem. If other lines trigger errors they will also be skipped with no feedback that it is happening. I would wager that although it's created your file and the steps appear to have been carried out something will be missing.

Comment: All the VBScript does is run an excel macro though, so if it was missing something then the only possible thing that it would be missing is running the macro. The file is getting produced so it is running

Comment: @E_McAndrew ok, I've said my piece. I'll wait for your next question when you realise it isn't working.

Comment: @E_McAndrew try the full **Edited** VBScript I have above, I tested it, it runs without returning an error

Comment: Thanks bud that seems to have done the trick