# VBA running an embedded macro

Tags: vba, excel

I have a script which I want to run the embedded macro within an excel file.

Within my script I have the below:

```
Option Explicit

ExcelRunMacro

Sub ExcelRunMacro()

  Dim xlApp
  Dim xlBook

  Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

  Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("Libraries\Documents\Spreadsheet.xlsm", 0, True)
  xlApp.Run "Macro"
  xlApp.Quit

  Set xlBook = Nothing
  Set xlApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

I know the issue is not within my Macro as this runs as expected when run manually within the spreadsheet.

I get the following error when I run the script:

```
Line: 8
Char: 3
Error: Unknown runtime error
Code: 800A9C68
Source: Microsoft VBScript runtime error
```

Comment: Use the full path for the document `"C:\...\.."

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unknown Runtime Error VB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42415948/unknown-runtime-error-vb)